# Is there a better hands-on, concrete way to learn Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have started several Javascript books and read about variables, loops, arrays, all of the intro material. I still find it difficult to grasp. I am doing a course on FreeCodeCamp which is very confusing and unclear, and I think the reason why it's so unclear to me is because of the way it's being presented: the same way I've seen on CodeAcademy and in textbooks.

For example, I learned HTML and CSS by building websites. Does anyone know of a way I can learn Javascript by building stuff, and learning how each piece of code can function in a real-life setting?

I see examples where we create arrays of lists of names and correspond them with ages and maybe genders. But how would I be using arrays in order to build something? What would be the type of thing I could build with that kind of information?

Sorry if this question is confusing, but I am a beginner and hoping that there is a way I'll be able to learn. I just keep hitting walls where it's like Greek to me.

Comment: the same way you would any other code project.

Comment: For some learning problems, there is no substitute for a real (human) teacher.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a question suited to SO, but because of your eagerness, I will impart a secret only known among developers... The way to learn a new language is to simply make apps using that language. It doesn't matter if they're useless, basic, or even broken. So long as you know that you've learnt something, you're progressing (my first app in JS was writing the 100 green bottles song to the HTML DOM using a loop).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Don't worry about it, but please be mindful of the appropriate sites for questions.

Comment: [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com) is great.  You will have projects to do and each time the project will get harder and harder.  Check out Javascript Essential Training and Foundations of Programming: Fundamentals on the Lynda.com website.  Both are taught by Simon Allardice and are excellent.

Comment: Javascript tag info option on SO, has Codewars site. Maybe you'll like it: http://www.codewars.com